# pfSense: How to set OpenVPN client as default gateway for just one interface?

Tags: networking, firewall, openvpn, pfsense

I have two LAN interfaces, 192.168.2.1 and .31.1 on my pfSense VM, with VLAN ID 2 and 31, and two WAN interfaces, one to my ISP and another an OpenVPN client to PIA.

I've set the default firewall "allow any" rule on the .31 interface to use the OpenVPN interface as the gateway and it works as expected, whatismyip.com shows the VPN IP address for clients on the .31 subnet. However, traffic originating from the pfSense box itself on .31 goes out over the WAN interface, like it's bypassing the firewall rule.

How do I redirect this traffic to the OpenVPN interface?